# get a well-formatted tracklist from a music Subreddit

Tags: php, json, regex, formatting, reddit

I'm trying to build an audio player based on music Subreddits.
I know it is possible to use the API and fetch a feed, like this one :

https://www.reddit.com/r/vintageobscura.json

That's quite helpfull to get the title attribute of each node.
But their format is not uniform, and I get very different results, eg.

> 1. I Level -- In The River (12" Version)
> 2. Flypops - Let Me Stay In The Sunshine (France, Psych) [1979?] killer drums (youtube.com)
> 3. Lola Payola - I got married to a man from space [UK/1981] (Odd Synthpop, Cosmic)
> 4. Bluey Robinson - 'Questions' [R&B/Hip-Hop]
> 5. KOKOKO! -- We are KOKOKO! [dance/world/electronic] (2017) electronic music made from junk in the heart of the D.R. Congo
> 6. Bareback, by Krono
> 7. Rebel son - 1-2-3 (Offical Audio)

What I want is a list of artists + titles (especially because I would like to be able to scrobble the tracks with last.fm - so the track information should be correct)

Is there a way to get that, or my only option is to filter it with regexes ?  Knowing that there is so much different titles format that this will obviously be quite hazardous.

[Radd.it](http://radd.it/r/Music/music) manages to do it, I don't know how; but their datas seems OK.
There is also https://reddit.musicplayer.io/, which do not filter titles.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: Regex-scan for common patterns, or decipher (e.g. ID3 or youtube-dl --w*-info-json) the target streams.

Answer (score 0):

[/r/music](https://www.reddit.com/r/Music/) has uniform submission titles. I wrote a script that commented on submissions with Spotify track recommendations based on the title ([source code here](https://github.com/lincoln-b/reddit-scripts/blob/master/recommend.py)). For reference, my regex to get the title was:

```
regex = r"^([\w\s\/\.,&\+']+ - [\w\s\/\.,&\+\"]+).*\[[\w\s\/\.,&\+'-]+\]$"
```

That was in Python. The equivalent PHP regular expressions should be:

```
$regex = '/^([\w\s\/\.,&\+']+ - [\w\s\/\.,&\+\"]+).*\[[\w\s\/\.,&\+'-]+\]$/';
```

I'm not the best with regular expressions, so there may be ways to simplify this. You can test out regular expressions [here](https://regex101.com/).

For the other subreddits, you're on your own, unless you want to get the link URL attribute. If the submissions are links to official YouTube videos, you can use the YouTube API to get meta data from those videos with artist name, etc. Someone asked your follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22910865/how-can-i-extract-artist-and-song-information-from-youtube-music-videos).

Understanding natural language is notoriously tricky. Good luck :-)